# Auto-hide the Back/Start/Search bar

Tags: settings, windows-10-mobile

Is there an option to enable the autohidng of the bottom bar?

It might be a bug in the version I'm running (10.0.10586.29), but my bar doesn't hide anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I've had some luck in finding something which is not an answer, but very helpful for me: Swipe up on the bar to hide it.

The bar seems to have switched its default state to being there on the Start screen, and even for each new app launch, but all that's needed to do is to swipe up to hide it or unhide it.